# Getting the "Visual Studio Debug Engine Sample" running in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to get the [Visual Studio Debug Engine Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Debug-Engine-c2e21c0e) running in 2017 Professional.

When I'm debugging according to the Walkthrough1.docx I can't see the Tools->Project Launcher menu.

The ProjectLauncherPackage doesn't seem to be loaded since my breakpoints is whited out.

---

This is what I did to make it work so far:

- Updated the Windows SDK Version in the SampleEngineWorker;
- Added

  - DiaStackWalkHelper::numberOfFunctionFragmentsForVA
  - DiaStackWalkHelper::functionFragmentsForVA
  - SymbolEngine::NumberOfFunctionFragmentsForVA
  - SymbolEngine::FunctionFragmentsForVA
- Changed SampleEngine and ProjectLauncher to be x86
- Updated source.extension.vsixmanifest

  - Install targets to 15,16
  - Dependencies to Visual Studio MPF 15.0
- Added Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework version 15 from nuget.

Comment: Please share the visual studio 2017 project via onedrive.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT Here it is: https://hiq365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/carl_ribbegardh_hiq_se/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=06e2a4f5f6a454cd0a80bf932cd534861&authkey=AWOQ841_mReG-1-RXowd0GI

Comment: I have download your project and encounter a issue, which said could not start up library project directly. https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlvaNEnglADDgRG3BERupN67NqTk, I would suggest create a new custom command project and modify it.